# UILabel find height that fits width

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I have a `UILabel` that I need to have a specific text size and frame width (matching the screen width). I want to be able to set the label's height to the minimum height that will fit all of the label's text without cutting it off.

I've tried the following:

```
let label = UILabel()
label.text = longText
label.numberOfLines = 0
label.sizeToFit()
```

But this won't work if `longText` is something like `"This string is really long, longer than the screen width"` as `sizeToFit` puts that entire string on one line and the text gets cut off with `...` when it reaches the screen width.

I then tried setting the label's width to match the screen width after calling `sizeToFit`. This lets the line wrap but doesn't adjust the label's height, so the string is still cut off after the first line.

Also, setting `label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true` won't work because I need the label to have a specific font size.

What I'd like to have is some kind of function like `label.minimumHeightForWidth:` where I can pass `UIScreen.main.bounds.width` as the width parameter and get a height that will fit the label's text on as many lines as needed with the given width parameter. Is it possible to do something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
let fixedWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width 
let newSize = lbl.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
lbl.size = CGSize(width:fixedWidth, height: newSize.height)
```